# Годовалый и снова годовалый?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, знаки

> #### Годовалый
>
> Активный участник на протяжении года, с репутацией не менее 200. Знак можно получать многократно

И действительно [можно получать многократно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=12123):

[image: скриншот]

**А объясните, как? Или это такой бонус за выход из бана?**

Для тех, кто не заметил: все 3 знака получены в январе 2017 года.

UPDATE: Пару часов назад он разбанился снова, но 4го знака пока нет.

Comment: Так он давно зарегистрирован на сайте, просто реально активен стал с 31 декабря, есть ответ с +3 с 2014 года. Или вопрос откуда 200 репутации взялось?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, у него 3 знака и все выданы в 2017 году. Два из них 2 января и один 18го. Вот [у тебя 3 знака](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=14963) выданы примерно по одному в год - подозреваю, что первый за достижение 200, а остальные - по штуке в год?

Comment: да кстати, у Вадизара какой-то странный паттерн. Может это как данные побились при переезде с хк

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, а у меня подозрение, что по знаку за каждый бан, точнее, разбан. Там же происходит изменение с 1 до реальной репутации :)

Comment: для проверки гипотезы осталось найти старого участника про которого достоверно известно что он был в бане)

Comment: Но по мне больше похоже на то что "активный участник" не обязательно должен быть активным, а просто иметь кап репы в 200 =)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму кто готов войти и (может быть) выйти потом из бана для проверки гипотезы? :)

Comment: @alexolut, он сам через 6 дней разбанится - посмотрим, будет 4й знак, или нет)))

Comment: Надо Николая с горки (или качелей, где он там?) звать и проверять немедля! :)

Comment: Возможно, 4го и не будет, т.к. стаж <4 лет.

Comment: @alexolut, либо надо подождать до полуночи с хвостиком по UTC :)

Comment: @Qwertiy либо до нового бана!

Comment: @alexolut, интересно, что раньше))

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле, репа 200+ стала расти только в этом году у него, т.е. знаков вообще не должно быть ещё.